# scala: apache httpclient in multi-threaded environment

Tags: multithreading, scala, spark-streaming, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am writing a singleton class (Object in scala) which uses apache httpclient(4.5.2) to post some file content and return status to caller.

```
object HttpUtils{
  protected val retryHandler = new HttpRequestRetryHandler() {
    def retryRequest(exception: IOException, executionCount: Int, context: HttpContext): Boolean = {
      //retry logic
      true
    }
  }
  private val connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager()

  // Reusing same client for each request that might be coming from different threads . 
  // Is it correct ????
  val httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
    .setRetryHandler(retryHandler)
    .build()

  def restApiCall (url : String, rDD: RDD[SomeMessage]) : Boolean = {
    // Creating new context for each request
    val httpContext: HttpClientContext = HttpClientContext.create
    val post = new HttpPost(url)

    // convert RDD to text file using rDD.collect

    // add this file as MultipartEntity to post

    var response = None: Option[CloseableHttpResponse] // Is it correct way of using it ?
    try {
      response = Some(httpClient.execute(post, httpContext))
      val responseCode = response.get.getStatusLine.getStatusCode
      EntityUtils.consume(response.get.getEntity) // Is it require ???
      if (responseCode == 200) true
      else false
    }
    finally {
      if (response.isDefined) response.get.close
      post.releaseConnection() // Is it require ???
    }
  }
  def onShutDown = {
    connectionManager.close()
    httpClient.close()
  }
}
```

Multiple threads (More specifically from spark streaming context) are calling `restApiCall` method. I am relatively new to `scala` and `apache httpClient`. I have to make frequent connections to only few fixed server (i.e. 5-6 fixed URL's with different request parameters).

I went through multiple online resource but still not confident about it.

- Is it the best way to use http client in multi-threaded environment?
- Is it possible to keep live connections and use it for various requests ? Will it be beneficial in this case ?
- Am i using/releasing all resources efficiently ? If not please suggest.
- Is it good to use it in Scala or there exist some better library ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend you to use `https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http` They have explicit warranty that the API is thread safe.  It looks like the Apache HTTPClient needs particular multi-threading considerations. http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/threading.html

Comment: I am using client version 4.5.2. the link describe 3.x

Answer (score 0):

It seems the [official docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) have answers to all your questions:

> 2.3.3. Pooling connection manager
>
> PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager is a more complex implementation
>   that manages a pool of client connections and is able to service
>   connection requests from multiple execution threads. Connections are
>   pooled on a per route basis. A request for a route for which the
>   manager already has a persistent connection available in the pool will
>   be serviced by leasing a connection from the pool rather than creating
>   a brand new connection.
>
> PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager maintains a maximum limit of
>   connections on a per route basis and in total. Per default this
>   implementation will create no more than 2 concurrent connections per
>   given route and no more 20 connections in total. For many real-world
>   applications these limits may prove too constraining, especially if
>   they use HTTP as a transport protocol for their services.

---

> 2.4. Multithreaded request execution
>
> When equipped with a pooling connection manager such as
>   PoolingClientConnectionManager, HttpClient can be used to execute
>   multiple requests simultaneously using multiple threads of execution.
>
> The PoolingClientConnectionManager will allocate connections based on
>   its configuration. If all connections for a given route have already
>   been leased, a request for a connection will block until a connection
>   is released back to the pool. One can ensure the connection manager
>   does not block indefinitely in the connection request operation by
>   setting 'http.conn-manager.timeout' to a positive value. If the
>   connection request cannot be serviced within the given time period
>   ConnectionPoolTimeoutException will be thrown.

Comment: I have read this documentation but that doesn't have any detailed example/explanation of resource release. I have gone through there Api's documentation as well but didn't get anything useful.